# JSON payload with POST to laravel store method

Tags: rest, laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel RESTful controllers for use with a JSON API

```
Route::resource('api/v1/users', 'UserController');
```

The controller has a [number of methods/actions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/controllers#restful-resource-controllers) which the HTTP verbs correspond to. The `store` action corresponds to the `POST` verb.

When I `POST` a JSON payload to `api/v1/users/6/` I instead hit the `show` method which is meant to use `GET`.

If I `POST` the JSON payload to `api/v1/users/` as is listed in the docs, I instead hit the `index` method which is also `GET`.

If I use `PUT`, the update method is correctly called. If I use `DELETE` the destroy method is correctly called. If I use `GET` on `api/v1/users/` and `api/v1/users/1/` the index and show methods are correctly called.

I cannot get the `store` method to trigger at all. I am using Postman to test

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a slash..

`api/v1/users` instead of `api/v1/users/`